# Unable to compare two string with strcmp and lowering with strlwr

Tags: c, string

Im trying to compare to strings but before that i want it to lowering to avoid problems at the compare time

```
cannot convert `bool' to `const char*' for argument `2' to `int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'
```

Both are strings, i dont get why the compiler say me that.

```
for (el = 0;el < p ; el++){
    if (strcmp(strlwr(catalogo[el].nombre),(strlwr(prod_elimi))==0)){

    }
}
```

Comment: change to `if (strcmp(strlwr(catalogo[el].nombre), strlwr(prod_elimi))==0){`

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: working BLUEPIXY 1, thank you very much!

Comment: Keep in mind that `strlwr()` modifies a string **in place**. It doesn't create a new lowercase string.

Comment: compile with `all warning` and `warnings as errors`. This kind of error should be catch by the compiler.

Comment: im using dev-C++ i dont know if its good enough.

Comment: Well, it _was_ caught by the compiler...

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
if (strcmp(strlwr(catalogo[el].nombre), strlwr(prod_elimi))==0){
```

The problem was with the paranthesis